# Creating categories according to several criteria's

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to created a category called emotional_ipv using the following criteria:

Having experienced no IPV if all responses are “never”; an isolated incident of IPV if one response is “once”; a low frequency of violence if the response is “once” to more than one item; a mid frequency if they respond “a few times” to at least one item, but do not respond “many times” to any item; and a high frequency if there are any responses of “many times”.

df

```
df <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245","191-2365", "191-4532", "191-9901", "191-2710", "191-5098"), ipv_q1_en = c("0", "1", "3", "0", "2", "2", "3", "2", "0", "2"), ipv_q2_en = c("0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "2", "0", "1", "0", "3"), ipv_q3_en = c("0", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2", "0", "1", "0","2"),ipv_q4_en = c("0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "2", "0", "1", "0", "3")),class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -10L))
```

coding key...0 Never;1 Once;2 Few times;3 Many times

Desired dataset:

```
df1 <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245",                                   "191-2365", "191-4532", "191-9901", "191-2710", "191-5098"),ipv_q1_en = c("0", "1", "3", "0", "2", "2", "3", "2", "0", "2"),ipv_q2_en = c("0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "2", "0", "1", "0", "3"), 
ipv_q3_en = c("0", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2", "0", "1", "0", "2"),ipv_q4_en = c("0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "2", "0", "1", "0", "3"),emotional_ipv = c("never", "low frequency", "high frequency", "mid frequency","mid frequency","mid frequency", "mid frequency", "high frequency", "never", "high frequency")),class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -10L))
```

What I have tried

```
df %>% select(subject_id, ipv_q1_en:ipv_q4_en) %>% ifelse(ipv_q1_en == 0 & ipv_q2_en == 0 & ipv_q3_en == 0 & ipv_q4 == 0, "never", ifelse(sum(ipv_q1_en:ipv_q4_en == 1, "isolated incident")),ifelse(ipv_q1_en <= 2 & ipv_q2_en <= 2 & ipv_q3_en <= 2 & ipv_q4 <= 2, "mid frequency",ifelse())
```

so the above code definitely won't work but I do not know how else to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (and add `na.rm = TRUE` arguments in case you have missing values in your data):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define dataframe
df <-tibble(
    subject_id = c(
      "191-5467",
      "191-6784",
      "191-3457",
      "191-0987",
      "191-1245",
      "191-2365",
      "191-4532",
      "191-9901",
      "191-2710",
      "191-5098"
    ),
    ipv_q1_en = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L),
    ipv_q2_en = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L),
    ipv_q3_en = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L),
    ipv_q4_en = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L)
  )

# reshape longer
df <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(
    !subject_id,
    names_to = "question",
    names_pattern = "ipv_q(\\d+)_en",
    values_to = "answer")

# add case distinction
df |> 
  group_by(subject_id) |> 
  summarise(emotional_ipv = case_when(
    sum(answer) == 0 ~ "never",
    sum(answer == 1) == 1 ~ "isolated incident",
    sum(answer == 1) > 1 ~ "low frequency",
    sum(answer == 2) >=1 & !any(answer > 2) ~ "medium frequency",
    any(answer == 3) ~ "high frequency"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    subject_id emotional_ipv    
#>    <chr>      <chr>            
#>  1 191-0987   medium frequency 
#>  2 191-1245   isolated incident
#>  3 191-2365   medium frequency 
#>  4 191-2710   never            
#>  5 191-3457   high frequency   
#>  6 191-4532   high frequency   
#>  7 191-5098   high frequency   
#>  8 191-5467   never            
#>  9 191-6784   low frequency    
#> 10 191-9901   low frequency
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The reason why your `ifelse()` statements do not work is that you need to wrap them inside `mutate()` if you want to modify columns. If you prefer not to make your data longer, you need `rowwise()` to allow aggregation across columns.